# One of arguments' values is out of range

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void houghTransform(int,void*);
Mat image,lines,dst,cdst;
int thresh;
const char* imageWindow = "Image Window";

int main()
{
    image = imread("DSC01894.jpg");

    //Turning the dst image into greyscale


    if(image.data!=0)
    {
        cv::Canny(image,dst,50,200,3);
        cv::cvtColor(dst,cdst,CV_GRAY2BGR);

        cv::createTrackbar("Threshold",imageWindow,&thresh,255,houghTransform);
        houghTransform(0,0);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Image cannot be read" << endl;
    }

    namedWindow("Image");
    imshow("Image",image);

    waitKey(0);

}

void houghTransform(int, void *)
{
    vector<Vec4i>lines;

    cv::HoughLinesP(dst,lines,1,CV_PI/180,thresh,50,10);

    for(size_t i=0;i<lines.size();i++)
    {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];

        cv::line(cdst,Point(l[0],l[1]),Point(l[2],l[3]),Scalar(0,0,255),3,CV_AA);
    }

    imshow(imageWindow,cdst);
}
```

When this is runing, I am getting a run time error,

`One of arguments' values is out of range`.  It should be in

`cv::HoughLinesP(dst,lines,1,CV_PI/180,thresh,50,10);` or

```
cv::line(cdst,Point(l[0],l[1]),Point(l[2],l[3]),Scalar(0,0,255),3,CV_AA);
```

Why is this?

Comment: It might be more helpful if you identify which function generates the error and what input parameters you are passing

Comment: Isn't this what debuggers are for? Or print statements and try/catch?

Comment: @user2151446: Can you install a debugger for QT Creator working with VS 2010 compiler? Let me know if you can

Comment: can you just check the values by std::cout<<l[0]<<" "<<l[1]<<" "<<l[2]<<" "<<l[3]; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this exception, which is

```
OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (rho, theta and threshold
 must be positive) in unknown function, file C:\slave\builds\WinInstallerMegaPac
 k\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp, line 718
```

which is at this code

```
    if( rho <= 0 || theta <= 0 || threshold <= 0 )
        CV_Error( CV_StsOutOfRange, "rho, theta and threshold must be positive" );
```

in `cvHoughLines2()` which is called by cv::HoughLinesP().

The arguments passed in to `HoughLinesP()` are:

```
rho=1
theta=0.0174533
threshold=0
```

There is the problem: threshold is not allowed to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vec4i l = lines[i];
```

Here,  `l` may have only one element

Or in:

```
cv::line(cdst,Point(l[0],l[1]),Point(l[2],l[3]),Scalar(0,0,255),3,CV_AA);
```

line end points may indicate the out of the boundaries of the image. you can check `Point(l[0],l[1])` and `Point(l[2],l[3])` if `l` have lass than 4 elements,  then other remaining points are just garbage and may have some huge values which `line()` method can not handle naturally.